# Syntax highlight request: Elixir

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to request that Elixir syntax highlighting support is included in StackOverflow's HighlightJS bundle and applied to the [elixir] tag.

It is [supported by HighlightJS](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/elixir.js) and would add about 2.23 Kb to the bundle after minification (tested by pasting into [jscompress.com](https://jscompress.com)).

More info is on the [original question I asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404965/266069) when I found out it wasn't working but didn't understand SO only bundles a subset of languages.

There are currently 8,219 questions with the Elixir tag at the moment. While the number of new new questions has unfortunately been decreasing since a 2016 peak, 2020 showed a strong uptick:

[image: StackOverflow trends line graph of elixir tag usage from 2009 to 2021]

Comment: [Testing in the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360687/282094), it looks like if you force elixir it's no different than forcing erlang, one difference though is that the Erlang tag is *turned on*  while the Wiki for Elixir doesn't have the language enabled - either way the highlighting style differs from what is shown on the highlight.js demo page (URL accessible from the link above, of the Sandbox example).